# Eclipse Ant Build is not not compiling in Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jenkins

I am trying to schedule the following ANT build in jenkins to execute a java class. When I run the build configuration in Eclipse it compiles and excutes my java class. When I schedule and execute the build.xml in Jenkins it executes the build but fails to compile my java class. It then marks the build as completed successfully. I am running ANT Version 1.8.4 and Java version 1.7.0_03 in both eclipse and jenkins. I am not sure why Jenkins is failing to compile the class?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
     <!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
     <project basedir="." default="build" name="Sel_Framework_Grid">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<path id="TestNG.libraryclasspath">
    <pathelement location="../../../.eclipse/com.springsource.sts_2.9.1.RELEASE_1574885722/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.7.0.20120802_0752/lib/testng.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="Sel_Framework_Grid.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/activation.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/axis.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/bsh-1.3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-discovery.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-io-2.0.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-jxpath-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/commons-logging.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/cssparser-0.9.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/cxf-2.5.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/guava-10.0.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-all-1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/htmlunit-2.9.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/httpmime-4.1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.4-1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.4-1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jaxen-core.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jaxen-jdom.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jaxrpc.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jcommander-1.13.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jcspclasses.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jdom.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jna-3.3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/json-20080701.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-dep-4.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jython.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/mail.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/neethi-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/nekohtml-1.9.15.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/operadriver-v0.8.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/phwclasses.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/saaj.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/sac-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/saxpath.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/stax2-api-3.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/velocity-1.7.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/woodstox-core-asl-4.1.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/wsdl4j.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xmlschema-core-2.0.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/AspriseJavaPDF-free.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/im4java-1.3.1-1.5.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/im4java-1.3.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/jna-3.4.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.5.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/testng-6.5.1.zip"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/slf4j-nop-1.6.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/poi-3.8-20120326.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/netty-3.2.7.Final.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/webbit-0.4.8-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/dbunit-2.4.8-compatibileWithPoi-3.5-XLSXSupport.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/poi-ooxml-3.8-20120326.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-20120326.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/xbean.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/Aspose.Words.jdk16.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/ojdbc14.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/selenium-java-2.24.1-srcs.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/selenium-java-2.24.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/vim25.jar"/>
    <path refid="TestNG.libraryclasspath"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="Sel_Framework_Grid.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target name="BaseSet Test">
    <java classname="BaseSet" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <arg line="C:\temp\testng-customsuite.xml c:\Jenkinstest Firefox,IE,EN,Ready"/>
        <classpath refid="Sel_Framework_Grid.classpath"/>

    </java>
</target>
```

**Jenkins Console Output**

Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid
[Sel_Framework_Grid] $ cmd.exe /C '"C:\AutomatedTesting\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin\ant.bat -file buildA.xml -Dbuild.sysclasspath=false -buildfile C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid\buildA.xml && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'
Buildfile: C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid\buildA.xml

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:
     [echo] Sel_Framework_Grid: C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid\buildA.xml

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Finished: SUCCESS

**Eclipse Console Output**

Buildfile: C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid\buildf.xml
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
     [echo] Sel_Framework_Grid: C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid\buildf.xml
    [javac] C:\Users\blank\Documents\workspace-sts-2.9.1.RELEASE\Sel_Framework_Grid\buildf.xml:
build:
BaseSet Test:
     [java] [TestNG] Running:
     [java]   C:\temp\testng-customsuite.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not specifying a set of targets to run from your Jenkins build. This means the default target "build" will be run:

```
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
```

The target "BaseSet Test" is one running your java class. Appears to be missing. I'd suggest altering your Jenkins job to run the following targets instead

```
build, BaseSet Test
```